# Cannot find Navigation Provider in ABP

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am developing an application with the latest ABP with Angular. I'm loving the new template and can't wait to finish this application I'm building in it. But I can't find the navigation provider to set my menus on the UI. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you have created new template with Angular4. In that case, it does not contain navigation provider. Instead, we have included menu in the Angular4 code.

You can see and change menu from sidebar-nav.component.ts: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/master/angular/src/app/layout/sidebar-nav.component.ts#L12

Comment: Thanks Hikalkan. I discovered it yesterday after searching through the files. You are doing a tremendous job with ABP. I appreciate this remarkable effort of yours in trying to make enterprise application development as easy as possible. But I still recommend you provide some tutorials and documentation on using the template with Angular4 so adoption can be faster. Many thanks.

Comment: Actually there is a documentation (https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Startup-Template-Angular) but it does not contain a section related to menu. I created an issue to follow it: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2271